# How to use php to change letters in file name

Tags: php, batch-rename

I have a few thousand images in a directory that I need to change the file name for. I've googled a few options but none of them work for me.

I want to have the file names changed from 
ex: 47308_xyz_old.jpg  to 47308_new.jpg

Thanks.

Comment: what should be difference between old name and new name

Comment: This is quite broad, and SO is not a code-writing service. Please add the codes that you have tried and the problems you encountered, then we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$files = scandir(__DIR__);
foreach ($files as $file) {
    if(file_exists($file))
    rename($file, str_replace("xyz_old", "new", $file));
}
```

[scandir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)

[rename()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php)

Comment: Thanks for the code AZ but, unfortunately, it doesn't change any of the files. I followed the links but most of the info involves changing the whole name, removing or adding special characters and rename on directory move.

Comment: your files & directory should be writable

Comment: They are. I'm still not having any luck.

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone in the future:
I was unable to get any php script to work for batch renaming files in the directory so, I went with Commandline. I was also modest with the file count (actually above 350K) so command line might have been a better first option.
As I only wanted to change a small part of the filename,
changing:   47308_xyz_old.jpg to 47308_new.jpg
This was my solution

```
cd /var/www/vhosts/YOURDIR
Rename all *_old.jpg to new.jpg
for f in *_old.jpg; do 
mv -- "$f" "${f%_old.jpg}new.jpg"
done
```

Thanks